# How can I check that the nginx gzip_static module is working?

Tags: gzip, nginx

How can I check that nginx is serving the .gz version of static files, if they exist?

I compiled nginx with the gzip static module, but I don't see any mention of the .gz version being served in my logs. (I have minified global.js and global.css files with .gz versions of them in the same directory).

The relevant part of nginx.conf looks like this:

```
gzip  on;
gzip_static on;
gzip_http_version 1.0;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
gzip_vary on;

gzip_comp_level 2;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: For anyone who's using a precompiled nginx: To check if your nginx was compiled with the necessary argument `--with-http_gzip_static_module` run `nginx -V`

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Use strace. First, you need to detect PID of nginx process:

```
# ps ax | grep nginx
25043 ?        Ss     0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
25044 ?        S      0:02 nginx: worker process
```

Ok, so 25044 is the worker process. Now, we trace it:

```
# strace -p 25044 2>&1 | grep gz
open("/var/www/css/ymax.css.gz", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = 438
open("/var/www/css/patches/patch_my_layout.css.gz", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/var/www/yaml/core/iehacks.css.gz", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/var/www/js/koznazna5.js.gz", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/var/www/css/ymax.css.gz", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = 216
```

As you can see, it is trying to find .gz versions of files.

Comment: Of note: `strace` supports multiple PIDs by adding the `-p xyz` argument multiple times. Useful when you have multiple nginx worker processes.

Comment: If you touch the asset files on the server, and use an incognito/private mode tab on your browser, you will force the files to be re-served so the above technique can give guaranteed results without any caches getting in the way (hopefully).

Comment: Looks like original file is required https://gist.github.com/ancap/7412315 and cannot be deleted.

Comment: with strace the easier thing to do would be to "strace -fp $PID", where $PID is the PID of the master process.  The -f flag tells strace to trace all child processes as well.

Comment: strace -f "follows fork". So in my case where the forks already happened, it didn't work.

You can use `strace $(pidof nginx | xargs -n 1 echo '-p')`

Answer (score 22):

Change the content of the non-gzipped file. And then `touch` both files (simultaneously—that is: in the same instantiation of `touch`). If when you load the file in an browser (cache-wiped) you get the non-changed file, then nginx served the static-cached-gzipped file.

An easy way to avoid *“did I just fetch the cache?”* worries is to fetch from the command-line with `curl` since curl doesn’t cache.

Answer (score 19):

I would disable automatic compression and log `gzip_ratio`:

```
http {
   gzip off;
   gzip_static on;

   log_format log_with_ratio "... $gzip_ratio ...";

   server {
      access_log /var/log/nginx/file.log log_with_ratio;
   }
}
```

Note, that you may override `gzip`, `gzip_static` and `access_log` per server and location levels.

Comment: This is actually brilliant for testing if nginx is gzipping things on the fly ie (gzip on) but if you try to use it to see if gzip_static is on it will just output a hyphen ... (using nginx 1.2.6). However if you have gzip_static on and gzip off and the content-encoding is gzip, I think you can assume its working correctly

Answer (score 2):

There is some hint I've noticed regarding `ETag` response header.

If static file is served by nginx, then header looks like this: `ETag: "135a-BQhu6KL71dyeCXcVZme6ug"`, however, when nginx is compressing the response (through gzip module) it looks like this: `ETag: W/"135a-BQhu6KL71dyeCXcVZme6ug"` (notice `W/`).

You can use this as well as `Content-Encoding: gzip` to distinguish plain static files, pre-compressed static files, and files compressed on the fly.

Answer (score -2):

I usually use Chrome Dev tools and look at the file sizes for the files in question.

Comment: How is that going to help you know if the server gzipped on the fly or if it was using the already pre-compressed file?

Comment: The minus wasn't me.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Chrome Dev Tools via the Network tab if you enable the Content-Encoding column (right-click on the columns to enable/disable specific content in the table):

[Chrome Dev Tools with Content-Encoding column enabled screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSKSt.png)