# How to convert this apache rewrite into nginx?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

The following are apache rewrite rules for unity webgl

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
RewriteRule (.*)Data(.*)\.js $1Compressed$2\.jsgz [L]
RewriteRule (.*)Data(.*)\.data $1Compressed$2\.datagz [L]
RewriteRule (.*)Data(.*)\.mem $1Compressed$2\.memgz [L]
RewriteRule (.*)Data(.*)\.unity3d $1Compressed$2\.unity3dgz [L]
AddEncoding gzip .jsgz
AddEncoding gzip .datagz
AddEncoding gzip .memgz
AddEncoding gzip .unity3dgz
```

Currently on nginx i have the following

```
   location ~* \.(js|data|mem|unity3d)$
   {
   gzip_static on;

   if ($request_filename ~ "\.jsgz$" ) {
                rewrite ^(.js.gz)$ /$1.jsgz;
   }
   if ($request_filename ~ "\.datagz$" ) {
                rewrite ^(.data.gz)$ /$1.datagz;
   }
   if ($request_filename ~ "\.memgz$" ) {
                rewrite ^(.mem.gz)$ /$1.memgz;
   }
   if ($request_filename ~ "\.unity3dgz$" ) {
                rewrite ^(.unity3d.gz)$ /$1.unity3dgz;
   }
   }



   location ~* \.(jsgz|datagz|memgz|unity3dgz)$ {
   add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
   break;
   }
```

But it doesn't work, based on my understanding of the original apache rewrite, it suppose to automatically compressed js|data|mem|unity3d into gunzip format plus adding "gz" name in the end of filename, how to rewrite in nginx while gzip_static doesn't support custom filename ?

Answer (score 9):

You may have figured this out by now, but I stumbled on this question when struggling with the Apache to Nginx conversion myself.

Nginx has a module called gzip_static which will automatically look for pre-compressed versions of files and serve them if the client supports gzip.  This requires that you move files from the Compressed directory to the Data directory, and slightly change the file extensions:

**Before:**

```
# cd MyProject
# tree
.
|-- Compressed
|   |-- MyProject.datagz
|   |-- MyProject.html.memgz
|   |-- MyProject.jsgz
|   |-- fileloader.jsgz
|   |-- UnityConfig.jsgz
|   |-- UnityProgress.jsgz
|-- Data
|   |-- MyProject.data
|   |-- MyProject.html.mem
|   |-- MyProject.js
|   |-- fileloader.js
|   |-- UnityConfig.js
|   |-- UnityProgress.js
```

**After:**

```
# tree
.
|-- Compressed
|-- Data
|   |-- MyProject.data
|   |-- MyProject.data.gz
|   |-- MyProject.html.mem
|   |-- MyProject.html.mem.gz
|   |-- MyProject.js
|   |-- MyProject.js.gz
|   |-- fileloader.js
|   |-- fileloader.js.gz
|   |-- UnityConfig.js
|   |-- UnityConfig.js.gz
|   |-- UnityProgress.js
|   |-- UnityProgress.js.gz
```

**In your Nginx config:**

```
location /path/to/MyProject/Data {
    gzip_static on;
}
```

Note that Nginx must be built with --with-http_gzip_static_module.  You can check to see if your version has this already by running:

```
nginx -V
```

The only drawback is that you have to move/rename the files, but that is a minor inconvenience for a one-liner solution.

Here's how to move/rename the gzip files to match what nginx expects:

```
cd Data
mv ../Compressed/*gz ./
rename 's/(.*)gz$/$1.gz/' *gz
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to tell if this is actually working? I did everything described here, it makes sense to me, gzip is enabled and installed in nginx but it seems like its downloading too long/downloading the full version and not the compressed version.

Comment: To test this for myself, I just peeked at the file size for both compressed and uncompressed files, cleared browser cache, and then watched the monitor tab in chrome/firefox dev tools to see what the file size was.

If you want to be more technical with it, see the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460821/how-can-i-check-that-the-nginx-gzip-static-module-is-working

Comment: @RobertNoack You can also check in browser console: "network" tab, click on one of the file supposed to be compressed, then in the "Response Headers" you should read "Content-Encoding:gzip" (when reloading the page maybe it couldn't appear since the browser will use the cached files)

Comment: Regarding Jody's answer, rather than rename the files simply symlink them. then you wont have to do it for every build.

Answer (score 0):

Doing an automated conversion of Unity's .htaccess using http://winginx.com/en/htaccess yields this:

```
# nginx configuration
location / {
  rewrite (.*)Data(.*)\.js /$1Compressed$2\.jsgz break;
  rewrite (.*)Data(.*)\.data /$1Compressed$2\.datagz break;
  rewrite (.*)Data(.*)\.mem /$1Compressed$2\.memgz break;
  rewrite (.*)Data(.*)\.unity3d /$1Compressed$2\.unity3dgz break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. I tested it on nginx/1.2.1.

```
location ~* ^/new/build/webgl_build/Release/.+\.(js|data|mem|unity3d) {
    add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
    gzip_static on;

    rewrite (.*)Release(.*)\.js $1Compressed$2.jsgz break;
    rewrite (.*)Release(.*)\.data $1Compressed$2.datagz break;
    rewrite (.*)Release(.*)\.mem $1Compressed$2.memgz break;
    rewrite (.*)Release(.*)\.unity3d $1Compressed$2.unity3dgz break;
}
```

I hope it will help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

How to do it on 5.5:

1) Go to Release folder and Rename all file extensions ending with **.extensiongz** to **.extension.gz**

2) Make sure your files don't have any spaces in them, I always leave mine snake_cased

3) Make sure you have static gzip installed with nginx by running **nginx -V**

4) Update your sites-available configuration file with:

```
location ~* {
        gzip_static on;
}
```

5) Restart nginx with **sudo service nginx restart**